# MP3 to Music Sheet Converter

Tags: gratis, music

Is there any software which converts mp3 to a music sheet properly?
I've tried IntelliScore but it did not work as I expected.

OS: Windows/Linux

Input file: audio file (mp3 for example)
Output file: a sheet (pdf, tef, gpx, or other format)

Comment: What is the issue with IntelliScore?

Comment: Which operating system? Free, or are you willing to pay? And must have features, other than "converts mp3 to a music sheet"? The more information you provide, the more help that we can give.

Comment: IntelliScore do not work properly. I want something free for Linux/Windows.

Comment: do not work properly = poor transcription accuracy?

Comment: Yes. It has poor accuracy.

Comment: Apparently Sibelius can do it, it has a free trial, but it's not free